# Could not load file or assembly in stimulsoft

Tags: c#, asp.net, stimulsoft

I'm working on asp.net webform project and created a stimulsoft report. When I click the button print this error pops up. please see image below

[image]

Comment: Check your solution if the assembly is correctly installed as a Reference

Comment: @MatchesMalone: hi, I already added all the references in the References.cs, is that the assembly your're saying?

Comment: @FrancisSaul Check out the version of the assembly is it correctly match with the web.config?

Comment: @Sankar: I don't know how to check assembly version.

Comment: @FrancisSaul Go to explorer, Locate your dll file, right click and choose properties, check the version in details tab.

Comment: @SankarRaj: I already changed the version , found out that the version is 2014, but still the same error. . .

Comment: @FrancisSaul Did you rebuild it?

Comment: @SankarRaj: yes, many times, I also do clean then rebuild still same error, I changed the version , but how about the publickeytoken? Do I need to change it also?

Comment: First say where is that ddl file. is there in Bin folder or not? How did you add the reference?

Comment: Yes, there is Bin folder, I added the references by right clicking on the References.cs and locate the dll files.